# How can I ignore all files except those with a certain extension in git?

Tags: git, gitignore

I need to ignore all files except those ending in `.php`, `.css`, `.html` or `.js`.

This is what I have in my .gitignore file for now:

```
*
!.php
!/*.php
!*.php
```

It does ignore everything, but only permits `.php` files in root directory, while hiding all the rest.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
*
!*/
!*.php
!*.css
!*.html
!*.js
```

Comment: Remember to add !.gitignore

Comment: This doesn't work as intended because it will track *all* files under directories, not just those of the desired extensions

Comment: As @jmborr says: this doesn't work as intended at all.

Comment: The key is `!*/`. Otherwise it ignores everything.

Answer (score 2):

For those, who would like to include file extensions which are located in subdirs like 
@jmborr and @Racso

```
# .gitignore for excluding all but certain files in certain subdirs

*
!*.cfg
!/**/
!certain/subdir/i_want_to_include/*.cfg
```

> when you exclude everything ('*'), you have to white-list folders ('/**/'), before being able to white-list files.

Found in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33983585/5388625