# Correctly ignore all files recursively under a specific folder except for a specific file type

Tags: git, version-control, directory, gitignore, subdirectory

I have seen similar questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852558/gitignore-only-allow-certain-extensions-and-files), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049835/how-can-i-ignore-all-files-except-those-with-a-certain-extension-in-git) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024924/gitignore-ignore-all-files-then-recursively-allow-foo)), but I don't get a proper solution from them.

I need to ignore all files under a particular folder except for a specific file type. The folder is a subdirectory for the root path. Let me name the folder `Resources`. Since I don't want to complicate things, let me ignore files under all folders named **`Resources`** wherever it is.

This is the most common solution (in all the duplicate questions)

```
# Ignore everything
*

# Don't ignore directories, so we can recurse into them
!*/

# Don't ignore .gitignore
!.gitignore

# Now exclude our type
!*.foo
```

The problem with this solution is that **it stops tracking newly added files** (since `*` ignores all files). I don't want to keep excluding each and every file type. I want normal behaviour where if any new file is added, `git status` shows it.

I finally got a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803689/gitignore-ignore-all-files-in-folder-hierachy-except-one-specific-filetype). The solution is to add another `.gitignore` file in `Resources` folder. This works correctly.

Can I achieve the same with one ignore file? I find having many ignore files in different directories a bit clunky.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
# Ignore everything under Resources folder, not elsewhere
Resources

# Don't ignore directories, so we can recurse into them
!*Resources/

# Now exclude our type
!*.foo
```

But this gives the opposite output. It ignores `*.foo` types and tracks other files.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

[@SimonBuchan is correct.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812717/correctly-ignore-all-files-recursively-under-a-specific-folder-except-for-a-spec/17821597#comment30450162_17821597)

Since git 1.8.2, `Resources/** !Resources/**/*.foo` works.

Comment: This works for me, slight tweak,  I just need to remove directories and everything below them so I did:`DirectoryName1/** DirectoryName1/**/*` for each of them. Firs remove directories but you need the second to remove all file types.

Answer (score 27):

The best answer is to add a Resources/.gitignore file under Resources containing:

```
# Ignore any file in this directory except for this file and *.foo files
*
!/.gitignore
!*.foo
```

If you are unwilling or unable to add that .gitignore file, there is an inelegant solution:

```
# Ignore any file but *.foo under Resources. Update this if we add deeper directories
Resources/*
!Resources/*/
!Resources/*.foo
Resources/*/*
!Resources/*/*/
!Resources/*/*.foo
Resources/*/*/*
!Resources/*/*/*/
!Resources/*/*/*.foo
Resources/*/*/*/*
!Resources/*/*/*/*/
!Resources/*/*/*/*.foo
```

You will need to edit that pattern if you add directories deeper than specified.

Comment: Thats sad.. Indeed I will have deeper directories, so I will stick with the first one :(

Comment: See further details on same solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803689/gitignore-ignore-all-files-in-folder-hierachy-except-one-specific-filetype -- also linked above by OP @nawfal

Answer (score 11):

This might look stupid, but check if you haven't already added the folder/files you are trying to ignore to the index before. If you did, it does not matter what you put in your .gitignore file, the folders/files will still be staged.

Comment: If someone runs into this specific use-case, you can use `git rm --cached <path to files>` to clear those ignored files out of git while still leaving them in the filesystem.

Answer (score 10):

Either I'm doing it wrongly, or the accepted answer does not work anymore with the current git.

I have actually found the proper solution and posted it under almost the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41112097/4094167). For more details head there.

Solution:

```
# Ignore everything inside Resources/ directory
/Resources/**
# Except for subdirectories(won't be committed anyway if there is no committed file inside)
!/Resources/**/
# And except for *.foo files
!*.foo
```

Comment: Yes, this works for me. Adding the `!/Resources/**/` was crucial to have git not ignore subdirectories.

Comment: I agree with you , the solution given by [Jim G](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25916709) is invalid in my case.
After reviewing the official documentation, I decided that the reason it was invalid was that the parent directory of those target files was still ignored, so using the exclamation mark was invalid, and then I saw your answer.I can work perfectly here.