# Add files to Git except some given file type

Tags: git

I suspect that this is a duplicate and should be easy, but I could not figure it out.

Suppose this is my folder structure

```
 - Parent folder
    - Folder1
    - Folder2
    - .git
```

Now I want to add all files in Folder2 except some file type say .xls, something of this sort

```
git add 'C:\Parent folder\Folder2' <except .xls>
```

Also let me know if I want to add a specific file type.

Thanks :)

Comment: add a `.gitignore` file to your root directory and following,
`*.xls` to it

Answer (score 1):

You can put a .gitignore file at the desired subdirectory. It will apply recursively to all subdirectories of that directory.

Github [maintains](https://github.com/github/gitignore) a collection of .gitignore templates. You may find it convenient to use.

Here is a relevant question: [Correctly ignore all files recursively under a specific folder except for a specific file type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812717/correctly-ignore-all-files-recursively-under-a-specific-folder-except-for-a-spec)

And another one you might find useful: [How to remove files that are listed in the .gitignore but still on the repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541615/how-to-remove-files-that-are-listed-in-the-gitignore-but-still-on-the-repositor)