# How to save Jenkins configuration?

Tags: jenkins

Is there any way to save a pipeline configuration  or an item configuration in Git or anywhere else, so that when my Jenkins machine is crashed, i can migrate the saved configuration in the new Jenkins instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would ( as a start ) get yourself - https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JobConfigHistory+Plugin which keeps history of all Changes made to Jobs , System config etc - has saved me multiple times.

Also , you could setup a cron job outside Jenkins to git push your Job config.

I setup to push the Jobs folder content ( including Build history - but you could exclude that - [Correctly ignore all files recursively under a specific folder except for a specific file type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812717/correctly-ignore-all-files-recursively-under-a-specific-folder-except-for-a-spec) ref ) .

My script ( i had SSH stuff previously setup )

```
cd /this/that/other/jenkins_data/jobs/
NOW=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y-%r")
git add .
git commit -m "Jenkins Backup $NOW"
git push -u origin jenkins-backup
```

This way gives me piece of mind , I have RSYNC to another box and I also have a Backup plugin running too... ( i was stung once - not again! )

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

All your jobs is stored in `config.xml` files inside `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/<path_to_your_job>` folders. So, you can just backup these `config.xml` files (or you can backup all Jenkins configuration by saving full `$JENKINS_HOME` folder).

Comment: I had to manually set `$JENKINS_HOME` to `/var/lib/jenkins`, hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can write the pipeline script in file and publish that file into the git.

After that just create the pipeline job in the jenkins and use `Pipeline script from SCM` option for pipeline script.

The other option is take backup of Jenkins home directory to external hard disk(keep project workspace outside the jenkins home to reduce backup size).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, "Pipeline script from SCM" is the script part right,iam asking about the configuration part of the pipeline, suppose i have a pipeline, pipeline x and in the configuration i have added it as a parameterized pipeline, and in the configuration i have also mentioned it as a"Pipeline script from SCM" and i have also scheduled this pipeline, this whole configuration setup of pipeline x, can i save it anywhere?

Comment: Yes you can mention this also in pipeline script. Go to any job and click on `Pipeline Syntax` at left side select `Declarative Directive Generator` and from dropdown select the option you want and click on generate you will get the syntax. add it in your pipeline script and done