# TFS plugin giving error after jenkins upgrade

Tags: jenkins, tfs, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have upgraded jenkins from `2.60.1` to `2.150.1`. After upgrade I am getting the below error while getting the code from TFS. I have upgraded the TFS plugin also.

```
FATAL: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: 36d215cc-c371-437a-9d54-2cf1f116d4bb.
com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.exceptions.SOAPFault: TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: 36d215cc-c371-437a-9d54-2cf1f116d4bb.
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAP12Service.examineResponseDOMForFault(SOAP12Service.java:117)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.examineBodyForFault(SOAPService.java:987)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequestInternal(SOAPService.java:665)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequest(SOAPService.java:444)
    at ms.tfs.versioncontrol.clientservices._03._Repository5Soap12Service.updateLocalVersion(_Repository5Soap12Service.java:1170)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.versioncontrol.internal.WebServiceLayer.updateLocalVersion(WebServiceLayer.java:3067)
Caused: com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: 36d215cc-c371-437a-9d54-2cf1f116d4bb.
```

Comment: Try to delete TFS plugin, restart Jenkins, then again install the plugin and check if there will be the same errors.

Comment: Still I am getting the same error after did the steps

Answer (score 2):

As I remember, TFS have the issue with path length - it cannot be more than 260 symbols, so try to use custom workspace for your job with a small name (like `C:\tfs_checkout`) to reduce the number of symbols in your path.

Comment: After upgrade there can be some differences in configuration and you need to re-configure your job. If you already checked tfs job configuration I can only recommend you to re-install Jenkins. Before that, you can [backup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54195533/10721592) your jobs `config.xml` files and then after re-installing Jenkins you can upload them from disk (`Manage Jenkins -> Reload Configuration from Disk`)

Comment: Thanks it is working fine. There was problem with characters length.

Comment: So, I was right about limiting path characters length, yes?

Comment: Yes that was correct. But actually that is working fine with older version TFS plugin.There was confusion.