# Git: .gitignore in subdirectories

Tags: git, exception, version-control, gitignore

I'm trying to manage my `neovim`'s `init.vim` with git. 
I want to ignore everything except the `init.vim` in the same folder as the `.gitignore`and one `kalisi.vim` in the directory

`/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/themes/`

**This is my current `.gitignore`:**

```
# Ignore everything
*

# Exceptions
!.gitinore
!init.vim

!bundle
bundle/*
!bundle/vim-airline
bundle/vim-airline/*
!bundle/vim-airline/autoload
bundle/vim-airline/autoload/*
!bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline
bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/*
!bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/themes
bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/themes/*
!bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/themes/kalisi.vim
```

**My thoughts about this:**

- Ignore everything: `*`
- Except this `.gitignore`: `!.gitgnore`
- And the `init.vim` in the same directory: `!init.vim`
- Also don't ignore the folder `bundle`: `!bundle`
- But everything in it: `bundle/*`
- Except the folder `vim-airline`: `!vim-airline`

I think you get the idea...

But if I execute `git status` now only get `bundle/` as untracked file. Should't I get `kalisi.vim` or `bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/themes/kalisi.vim`?

I'm hoping for a more elegant way to be honest. I also heard about placing multiple `.gitignore`'s in the directories, but the subdirectories are all projects with it's own `.gitignore` and this would create a huge amount of work to only not-ignore the right `.gitignore`.

I hope someone has an idea what to do, currently it just seems like the `bundle/` directory is tracked, but not the content I want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in "[How do I add files without dots in them (all extension-less files) to the gitignore file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19023985/6309)", there is one rule to remember with `.gitignore`:

[It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded. (<sup>`†`</sup>)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/6309)
(<sup>`†`</sup>: unless certain conditions are met in git 2.7+)

That means, when you exclude everything ('`*`'), you have to white-list folders ('`/**/`'), before being able to white-list files.

```
# Ignore everything
*

# Exceptions
!.gitinore
!init.vim
!/**/
!bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/themes/kalisi.vim
```

The [OP LastSecondsToLive](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5317317/lastsecondstolive) actually took a simpler approach:

> I created a commit with `bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/themes/kalisi.vim` then I switched my `.gitignore` back to:`* !.gitinore !init.vim` to ignore everything, but since `bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/themes/kalisi.vim` is already tracked, changes will get tracked in the future.

Comment: When using this `.gitignore` I *again* get *bundle/* (together with *old.bundle/* as only untracked files. It seems like now the whole `bundle/` is included. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @LastSecondsToLive you need to `git add bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/themes/kalisi.vim`, before a `git status` shows you what you want: if nothing is added yet, the status just stops at the first untracked folder.

Comment: Yeah, `git status` then shows `bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/themes/kalisi.vim` as staged, but now `bundle/neobundle.vim/`,  `bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/init.vim` and `bundle/vim-airline/t/` (*subdirectories of `bundle`*) are shown as untracked and I wanted to ignore these.

Comment: @LastSecondsToLive so try and those folders content (after the last rule), as `*.vim/*`.

Comment: It was still not working (the other sub-directories still showed up). This is what I did: I created a commit with `bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/themes/kalisi.vim` then I switched my `.gitignore`back to:`*   !.gitinore   !init.vim` to ignore *everything*, but since `bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/themes/kalisi.vim` is already tracked, changes will get tracked in the future.

Comment: Thank you really much for your time.

Comment: @LastSecondsToLive That will work! I have included your approach in the answer for more visibility.